# org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel- occures before subscriber bean is created

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement **ReplyingKafkaTemplate** with spring batch integration.

It is actually running eagerly and throwing the "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel" error before the subscriber bean is created. As you can see in the log.

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'kafka Cloud Task.gatewayinputchannel'.;
```

```
Adding {kafka:outbound-gateway:kafkaConfig.outGateway.serviceActivator} as a subscriber to the 'gatewayinputchannel' channel
2022-08-18 02:02:08.068  INFO 24232 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'kafka Cloud Task.gatewayinputchannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-08-18 02:02:08.068  INFO 24232 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'kafkaConfig.outGateway.serviceActivator'
```

**Is there a way to prevent it from running eagerly? and wait till all the beans are created.**

My ReplyingKafkaTemplate is described as below.

```
@Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "gatewayinputchannel")
    public KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, Message<?>> outGateway(
            ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, Message<?>, Message<?>> kafkaTemplate) {
        KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String,Message<?>> kpmh = new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String,Message<?>>(kafkaTemplate);    
        kpmh.setMessageKeyExpression(new LiteralExpression(kafka_processing_topic));
        kpmh.setTopicExpression(new LiteralExpression(kafka_processing_topic));
        kpmh.setOutputChannel(gatewayoutputchannel());
        return kpmh;
    }
```

---

Edited

```
@Configuration
@MessagingGateway
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public interface IntegrationGateway {
    
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "gatewayinputchannel", replyChannel = "gatewayoutputchannel")
    public Message<?> sendToKafka(Message<?> input);
    
}
```

We are calling it from the item processor of a batch job

```
Message<?> request= MessageBuilder.withPayload(inpMessage).copyHeaders(header).build();
            Message<?> response = integrationGateway.sendToKafka(request);
```

-------------------------- Edit 3 --------------------------
How you start the batch job ? :

We are trying to start the batch job from a spring boot project with @Scheduled method programmatically using JobLuncher.

I have below flag to prevent the job starting automatically.
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

```
2022-08-19 16:00:24.781 ERROR 13732 --- [         task-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step Synchronous Processing : Read -> Process -> Write  in job fixedLengthFileJob

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'IMPF Cloud Task.gatewayinputchannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=10001,Bruce,S,Willis,M,16/07/1974,#1 1st main,1st cross,Moody,Alabama,#2 2nd main,2nd cross,Acmar,Alabama,Mobile,(205)710-2385,,Landline,(20,01, headers={RunGUID=00a04208-c0d8-4354-97f0-c5d8bfb5368d, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@27192c74, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@27192c74, IngestionPath=/opt/usr/conf/xyz/, id=d52d89f7-4ec0-5c3e-b84b-be4dc58223b5, kafka_replyTopic=impf_int_batch_success, timestamp=1660905024776}]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:76) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:522) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:492) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:652) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:588) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:555) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:544) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.sendToKafka(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cloudtask.batchconfig.CloudTaskBatchSyncConfig.lambda$syncProcessor$2(CloudTaskBatchSyncConfig.java:204) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:210) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128) [spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy93.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.cloudtask.batchconfig.runner.JobRunner.runJob(JobRunner.java:71) [classes/:na]
    at com.cloudtask.batchconfig.runner.JobRunner.runFlatFileBatchJob(JobRunner.java:43) [classes/:na]
    at com.cloudtask.batchconfig.runner.JobRunner$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e5597de2.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) [spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:139) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.9.jar:5.5.9]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
```

--------------------------- Edit 4 Job laucnhing code---------------

```
@Bean
    @Scheduled( fixedRate = 150000L)
    public void jobScheduled(){
        logger.info("Job triggered");
        getAllFileNames().stream().forEach( fileName-> {

            jobRunner.runFlatFileBatchJob(fileName);

        });
    }
```

Thanks
Santrupta

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem of this `outGateway` bean and its `gatewayinputchannel` subscription. It is a problem of producer which sends to this `gatewayinputchannel` too early. So, share with us, please, what and how does that instead.

Comment: I have updates the question. And added the kafka configuration details. The producer details can be seen in that file as well. Kindly advice.

Comment: No, that doesn’t help. Please, remove that config: it is confusing. Show better what sends messages to that problematic channel

Comment: Hi @Artem Bilan , The question has been updated with requested details.

Comment: How do you start that batch job? Can you, please, share the whole stack trace for that `MessageDeliveryException`, so we would see how the message is sent to this channel?

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with your requested details.

Comment: Show the code, please, how you start that job.

Comment: Thanks Artem, for the reply. I ahve added the job launching code in the question.

Comment: See if `initialDelay` can help you: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

Comment: Hi Artem, Thanks for your support and help.... I succeeded by removing the <b>Bean</b> annotation from the Scheduled mehtod. <br/>   @Bean
    Scheduled( fixedRate = 150000L)
    public void jobScheduled(){

Comment: Oh! Right, the `@Bean` makes this method to be called during init phase - too early.